# How to set map(master) values to bean in Spring? How to show in jsp?

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

I had stored in map for `context-param` values from `web.xml` at startup *tomcat server* time.
I want store map values to *bean* and populate `jsp`.

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Are you saying that you want to create a map of values as a Spring bean and then access this map from a JSP?

Comment: Already i have stored some static and master values in classA. How to easily populate classA value in many jsp.

Comment: want to show list , map to jsp

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your comments, it looks as though you just need to expose the map on the model. Use a method annotated with `@ModelAttribute` in your controller, not `@RequestMapping`:

```
@Controller
public class YourController {

    @Autowired
    private ServletContext context;

    @ModelAttribute("staticValues")
    public Map<String, String> getStaticValues() {
        Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();  
        map.put("test1",context.getInitParameter("test1")); 
        map.put("test2",context.getInitParameter("test2")); 
        map.put("test3",context.getInitParameter("test3"));     
        map.put("test4",context.getInitParameter("test4")); 
        return map;
    }

    ...
}
```

And then in the jsp you can do:

```
<c:out value="${staticValues.test1}" />
<c:out value="${staticValues.test2}" />
<c:out value="${staticValues.test3}" />
...etc...
```

Comment: Again am Thank You Will Keeling. I had followed above code but am getting org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Could not instantiate bean class [javax.servlet.ServletContext]: Specified class is an interface.

Comment: Sorry - the ServletContext should be an autowired field. See updated answer.

Comment: Thank you very much for this help. How can I get this kind of concepts? where do you refer the Spring Concepts .can you share the study material or link.

Comment: I would start with the documentation on the Spring site. It's pretty comprehensive: http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.0.x/reference/mvc.html

Answer (score 0):

One way of achieving this would be to set classA up in your Spring configuration with the appropriate property config:

```
<bean id="classA" class="some.package.ClassA">
    <property name="propName" value="propValue"/>
    ...etc...
</bean>
```

You could then expose this in the view resolver configuration using the `exposeContextBeansAsAttributes` property:

```
<bean id="viewResolver"
    class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
    <property name="exposeContextBeansAsAttributes" value="true"/>
    <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/pages/"/>
    <property name="suffix" value=".jsp"/>
</bean>
```

And then in any jsp, you could access the properties of the classA bean directly:

```
<c:out value="${classA.propName}"/>
```

Comment: First Thanks your reply....I had followed above but am getting java.lang.IllegalStateException: Ambiguous mapping found. Cannot map 'mapDemoClass' bean method ....My expectation is following action are store in util method thats are master country list,some gmail contact import url store in web.xml. So i want populate dropdown in master country list in many jsp and populate gmail url in jsp.

Comment: Can you post the code for `classA` and the Spring config that you have configured?

Comment: Below for Controller code...........@RequestMapping("/staticValues")
  public HashMap<String, String> getStaticValues(ServletContext context){
  HashMap<String, String> hashMap=new HashMap<String, String>();
  
  hashMap.put("test1",context.getInitParameter("test1"));
  hashMap.put("test2",context.getInitParameter("test2"));
  hashMap.put("test3",context.getInitParameter("test3"));
  hashMap.put("test4",context.getInitParameter("test4"));
  
  return hashMap;
 }

Comment: then how can i set beans-servlet.xml for getting hashmap value

Comment: I have tried <s:eval expression="@staticController.getStaticValues()" var="mapValue" /> its also getting error